# According to Pentecostalism, was the Pope biblically justified in saying that an unbelieving man is in heaven?

Tags: soteriology, papacy, pentecostalism, pope-francis

[Pope Francis consoles a boy who asked if his non-believing father is in Heaven (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/bRbUTfSds0U)

Here we have a son asking the Pope whether his father would be granted admission in the Kingdom of God. His father is an atheist.

The Pope reasons that since he was a good man, he would not be rejected by God.

However,

> Ephesians 2:8 – For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God: Not of works, lest any man should boast.

Looking for answers from a Pentecostal perspective on whether this statement is biblically justified.

Comment: Hi Cute Baby, good to have you here, you should know though, this question might not garner the caliber of answers we'd like to have since you're asking about the current Pope and the teachings of a perspective that has no defacto teaching authority.    I don't think you really need to mention the Pope to ask this question because, to a Pentecostal, I don't think it would make any difference if he was the Pope or your next door neighbor.

Comment: Great editing done on this question, Nathaniel. Keep it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a crying boy ask that question is certainly a hard situation.

However, the entire New Testament is completely clear that without faith in Christ, proven by the way a person chooses to live their lives (repentance and good works based on faith in Jesus), it is impossible to please God.

I discern that the pope gave the boy, and everyone who heard, false hope. Many people baptize their children in the Catholic church "just in case", but neither believe nor live it themselves.

I have many family members who died without faith and repentance. It was hard to accept, but the Bible is clear they will not be in Heaven.

Lies never give God the glory.

*Someone pointed out I should at least give a few verses. They're right. Here you go:

- Revelation 21:7-8 "He that overcomes shall inherit all things; and I will be his God, and he shall be my son. 8 But the fearful, and unbelieving, and the abominable, and murderers, and whoremongers, and sorcerers, and idolaters, and all liars, shall have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone: which is the second death." Comment: the context of "he that overcomes" refers to those who keep their faith in Christ till they die, no matter how hard things get.
- John 3:18  "He that believes on him is not condemned: but he that believes not is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God."
- John 3:36 "He that believes on the Son has everlasting life: and he that believes not the Son shall not see life; but the wrath of God abides on him."
- John 12:48 "He that rejects me, and receives not my words,3  has one that judges him: the word4  that I have spoken, the same shall judge him in the last day."
- Romans 1:16 "For I am not ashamed of the gospel of Christ: for it is the power of God unto salvation to every one that believes; to the Jew first, and also to the Greek." (Greek here means everyone else besides Jews).

Comment: While I like this answer, I would hold my check for some time if anyone who thinks the Pope was biblically justified decided to respond. If not, I would check this.